# Ways to speed up SQL query on large table

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, query-optimization, where-clause

I have a MySQL table of 10 million rows and 3 columns, in following format:

```
id                                     time                               num

ca65e871-d758-437e-b76f-175234760e7b  2020-11-14T23:08:05.553770Z         11112222222
...
```

I am trying to count occurrences for particular number and within desired time frame, like this:

```
"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE time >'2020-11-14T23:08:05.553752Z' and num = '11112222222'"
```

I am running queries from Python environment (python 3.x) which is connected to MySQL database using `pymysql` package. On 10MM rows this execution lasts for around **2.8 seconds**. After adding index on both `time` and `num` columns, the execution is almost twice as fast: **1.5 seconds**.

My question is can I speed this up further?

Ideally, the execution time should be below 200 milliseconds, so I don't know if this is even possible. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please be more specific about your starting point like outlining the different layers and how they contribute to your query duration. You should trace different calls and inspect whether it is query execution, network transfer or Python-/ pymysql-overhead. At least sharding and parallel querying always works but increases compexity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM TABLE_NAME 
WHERE time > '2020-11-14T23:08:05.553752Z' AND num = '11112222222'
```

You want a multi-column index on `(num, time)`. The ordering of the columns in the index matters. You want the column that has the equality predicate first, then the column that has the inequality predicate.

I am a bit suspicious about the datatypes. If `num` is of a numeric datatype (it looks like `int`), then you should filter it against a literal number:

```
num = 11112222222
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I have added an index on `(num, time)` and the execution time now is under 5 milliseconds. Amazing advice, thanks again!
Btw, `num` is of type `bigint` and changing the filtering (against a literal number as you said) did not help much. Do you think that maybe I should turn that `num` column to type `varchar`? Does this helps in speeding the query further?

Comment: In that context, `'123'` is turned into `123` before starting the query.  So, you won't see a noticeable difference in speed.  The opposite is where programmers get screwed:  `varchar_col = 123` converts the column, not the `123`.  That is, in your case; keep `num` as `BIGINT` and don't worry about the literal.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to speed up the query further is to shrink the datatypes.

No change is needed with `num = '11112222222'`, but...

`BIGINT` is 8 bytes.  If you can live with a limit of 4 billion, use `INT UNSIGNED` (4 bytes).

Unfortunately, MySQL does not understand the string `'2020-11-14T23:08:05.553770Z'` as a `DATETIME` (nor `TIMESTAMP`) If `time` is a VARCHAR(27), then things are ok. But if you could switch to a compatible format, a lot of space would be saved with `DATETIME(6)`, which is only 8 bytes (versus 28 bytes for the varchar).

`UUIDs` are bulky and inefficient because of their randomness.  You are possibly using `CHAR(36) CHARACTER SET ascii` -- at 36 bytes.  Pack it (see MySQL 8.0) into `BINARY(16) -- 16 bytes.

Those would shrink the table and index significantly, thereby providing some improvement in performance.

For conversion code for UUIDs:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/uuid#code_to_do_it  Also MySQL 8.0 has a similar pair of builtins.

Also, the `T` and `Z` are not valid characters for `DATETIME(6)`, so some editing will be needed.

Comment: Thank you! I will use `datetime(6)` and `UUID` in packet `binary` form. Regarding the latter, I assume this is a good way of doing it? https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-uuid/

Comment: @Makaroni - I added a couple of paragraphs.